# css grid fr unit not displaying correctly

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

When I open the following code in google chrome, the header and signIn selectors span a much longer height than the .create selector even though they should both span one column. Would anyone have an idea as to what could cause this? Thank you

```
grid {
display: grid;
height: 1800px;
border: 2px blue solid;
grid-template: 1fr 1fr 1fr 7fr / repeat(8, 1fr);
}

header {
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 2;
border: solid red 2px;
}
.signIn {
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 2;
border: solid blue 2px;

}
.create {
grid-row-start:3;
grid-row-end:4;
border: solid blue 2px;
}
```

Comment: can you also share your HTML to show and reproduce your issue. This : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPYWgR works fine with my chrome .so does this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdoLXR

Answer (score 0):

To header and signIn you are giving

```
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 2;
```

where as to .create

```
grid-row-start:3;
grid-row-end:4;
```

so if you want create to be smaller or same you need to give it the small or similar `row-start` and r`ow-end` value

Comment: shouldn't they both just span one row = to 1fr though?